# PHP/MySQL Inserting In Wrong Column

Tags: php, mysql

Wrote my code to work with a specific .cvs format and it was working for the format of the files I had.  Now the format of the .cvs file has changed.

So now it looks like everything is inserting but it has shifted over.  More specifically everything has moved over one whole column to the right.

I was able to modify the code to make it move further over to the right, but I was unsuccessful at moving it to the left.

Here the part of my code that is having issues:

```
if($deleteSuccess == 1){

    echo "Now inserting all new records";
    $handle = fopen($target_file, "r");
    $count = 0;
    while (($data = fgetcsv($handle, 0, ",")) !== FALSE) {
      $name = $data[0];
      $correct0 = str_replace("'", "", $name);
      $correct1 = str_replace("'", "", $data[1]);
      $correct2 = str_replace("'", "", $data[2]);
      $correct3 = str_replace("'", "", $data[3]);
      $correct4 = str_replace("'", "", $data[4]);
      $correct5 = str_replace("'", "", $data[5]);
      $correct6 = str_replace("'", "", $data[6]);
      $correct7 = str_replace("'", "", $data[7]);


      $import="INSERT into DVDCatalog.testtable(`Volume Name`,`DVD Number`,`Type`,`Category`,`Date`,`Author`,`Availablity`,`Picture`) values('$name','$correct1','$correct2','$correct3','$correct4','$correct5','$correct6','$correct7')";
      $count = $count + 1;
      mysqli_query($conn, $import);
      if(mysqli_error($conn)){
          echo "<br> Problem with --> ".$import."<br>";
```

Thanks.

Comment: I'd recommend using more descriptive names for your variables, something like `$dvd_num` or such, because the way you've got it now is a little confusing to read.

Comment: why are you using `$name` instead of `$correct0` ?

Comment: Also it's really hard to replicate any error you're getting without the two things we need: the `create table` for the table you're using and a copy of the file you're trying to use (or just a string version added in to the post)

Comment: Thank you for posting the status report. Looks like you are just sharing the current status of your development efforts. Maybe I missed it... but was there a *question* you wanted to ask?

Answer (score 0):

If everything has moved over 1 column to the right, then the data that used to be in `$data[0]`, `$data[1]`, etc. is now in `$data[1]`, `$data[2]`, etc. To get insert data the same as you used to, you should not be doing anything with `$data[0]`, because that's the new field that was added to the CSV file but doesn't correspond to the old format.

So it should be:

```
  $correct0 = str_replace("'", "", $data[1]);
  $correct1 = str_replace("'", "", $data[2]);
  $correct2 = str_replace("'", "", $data[3]);
  $correct3 = str_replace("'", "", $data[4]);
  $correct4 = str_replace("'", "", $data[5]);
  $correct5 = str_replace("'", "", $data[6]);
  $correct6 = str_replace("'", "", $data[7]);
  $correct7 = str_replace("'", "", $data[8]);
```